# How to distribute nodes across all directions without overlapping in d3 chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts

I am trying to plot dependency graph using d3.

My plunkr what I have tried can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/kXlLhM2UziztoFfirX0u?p=preview

So, the node works fine, but it overlaps each other and only in one direction.

I am manually setting the distance between the node (because automatically not working)

```
var force = self.force = d3.layout.force()
                .nodes(data.nodes)
                .links(data.links)
                .linkDistance(function(d) { return (d.distance*10); })
                //.friction(0.5)
                .charge(-250)
                .size([w, h])
                .start();
```

But this makes node overlapping each other and also all the nodes are in same direction which is not intended. It should idealy spread across all direction.

Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: Best solution: spend some time and energy upgrading your code to D3 v4. Then, just use `forceCollide`.

Comment: will that (upgrade) has more breaking changes?because I already use it at many places..

Comment: Lots and lots of them. That's why I said *"spend some time and energy"*.

Comment: ok..let me see what else I can get out of this upgrade.. if its worth.. I will do that.